# How can I override GET/ok ELB-HealthChecker/2.0 in dropwizard?

Tags: java, dropwizard, health-check, aws-elb

I have a use case where I want to override the default behavior of ELB healthchecker. It currently succeeds in all scenarios but I want to check if the DB has no available connections or an external client is not responding, the healthcheck should fail.

is there a way I can do that in dropwizard by creating a custom resource or by some other configuration ?